# Push and select data from Array of Objects

Tags: javascript

So I have an Array of object like this :

```
    var dataQuestions = [ {
        question : 1,
        reponse : 3,
    },{
        question : 2,
        reponse : 7,
    },{
        question : 3,
        reponse : 5,
    }];
```

I want to add data in this array by clicking on a button (onclick action)
And the other button get the number of the reponse (ex: onclick(2) responce->7)

Comment: So what have you tried? Did you search for "How to add object to array" or "how to listen to click event"?

Comment: Yes, and I didn't found anything, that's why Im asking

Comment: What does your HTML look like, and what have you tried for the buttons part? Whats the context of the code?

Comment: I didnt display the html because all I want to do is how to set and get data to the array objects like the title of the post and then I will integrate the code to the html by myself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

besides lack of info provided , this might help you build your own

```js
 var dataQuestions = [ {
        question : 1,
        response : 3,
    },{
        question : 2,
        response : 7,
    },{
        question : 3,
        response : 5,
    }];
    
function addQ(){
        var question = parseInt(document.getElementById("question").value);
    var response = parseInt(document.getElementById("response").value);
    dataQuestions.push(
        {
       question: question,
       response : response
      }
    )
    console.log(dataQuestions);
}

function getResp(){
    var getResp = parseInt(document.getElementById("getresponse").value);
  var res = dataQuestions.find(q=>q.question===getResp);
  console.log(res.response)
}
```

```html
<label for="question">Question:</label>
<input type="text" id="question" ><br><br>
<label for="response">Reponse:</label>
<input type="text" id="response" >



<button onclick="addQ()">Add</button>

<br>
<br>
<label for="getresponse">Get Response of:</label>
<input type="text" id="getresponse" >

<button  onclick="getResp()">Get</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should ass your tries to the question.
Anyway, this is a simple solution that does what you asked:

```js
let responses = []
document.getElementById("collect").addEventListener("click", () => {
  responses = [];
  for(let el of document.getElementsByClassName("answer")){
    responses.push({
        question: el.id,
        answer: el.value
    });
 }
 });
 
 document.getElementById("show").addEventListener("click", () => {
    const placeHolder = document.getElementById("answer_list");
    placeHolder.innerHTML = "";
    responses.forEach((r) => {
      placeHolder.innerHTML += `Question: ${r.question} Answer ${r.answer} <br>`;
    });
 });
```

```html
<div>
  question 1: <input id="1" class="answer"/><br>
  question 2: <input id="2" class="answer"/><br>
  question 3: <input id="3" class="answer"/>
</div>
<div>
  <button id="collect">Collect answers</button> 
  <button id="show">Show answers</button> 
</div>
<div id="answer_list">
  
</div>
```